# (Eclipse) JBoss nunca inicia

Tags: java, eclipse, servidor, jboss, standalone

Estou tendo problemas ao tentar fazer o JBoss rodar no eu Eclipse. Eu instalei o JBossASTools, baixei a última versão do JBoss, e fiz o procedimento de instalação padrão de novo server no Eclipse (com o arquivo de configuração `standalone-full`). Porém, quando dou um `start`, são mostradas as seguintes mensagens no console:

```
22:01:45,321 INFORMAÇÕES [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
22:01:45,556 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
22:01:45,603 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
```

E então o server fica eternamente no estado de "starting" sem nunca de fato ser iniciado.

Meu Sistema Operacional é o Windows 8.1. Que devo fazer?

Comment: Está rodando com java 8?

Comment: Sim, estou com o Java 1.8

Comment: Blz, não funciona no java 8, já vou incluir uma resposta pra você.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A versão que você está usando (`JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final`) não roda no Java 8, na verdade nenhuma do community, é uma questão conhecida há um tempo. Veja este trecho desta [thread](https://developer.jboss.org/message/808212), comentado por um dos desenvolvedores:

> Yes it is normal.
>
> There have been some changes in JDK8 that prevent AS7 and current version of EAP6 to start under JDK8.
>
> We have many JDK8 related fixes in WildFly so I would recommend you to use that.
>   As for EAP goes, the start up on JDK8 is fixed in upcoming 6.2 release.
>
> So in short, I would be more then welcome if people would test WildFly on JDK8 as we are working on making whole testsuite pass on it.

Resumindo, existem algumas alterações no JDK8 que impedem o funcionamento do AS 7 e versões mais antigas do EAP 6 de rodar no JDK8.

Então, você pode seguir um dos seguintes procedimentos:

- rodar no java 7
- usar o WildFly (recomendo este, caso não queira instalar outra JRE)
- usar o JBoss EAP 6.4

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Esse WildFly é uma alternativa ao JBoss, ou um complemento? Estou fazendo uma apostila da K!9 e tenho receio de usar outro server que não seja o especificado...

Comment: Digamos que o WildFly seja o JBoss AS 8 (tanto é que o WildFly já começou da versão 8), ou seja, continua sendo desenvolvido pela JBoss/RedHat, mas com suporte a especificações mais recentes e outras melhorias, como de performande. O EAP é a versão com suporte comercial. É pouco provável que o que está na apostilha não funcione no WildFly, mas se preferir você pode instalar o java 7.